# Transition diagram for following token number

Tags: automata, compilers

**number ->  digits(.digits)?(E[+ -]?digits)?**
This transition diagram runs the  above mentioned token I can not understand this how this is work.what is meaning of "?"Symbol and digits. can anyone explain me this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**digits(.digits)?(E[+ -]?digits)?** is a regular expression for the set of strings that the pictured automaton accepts. That is, all of the strings accepted by the automaton will match this pattern. If you're unfamiliar with regular expression syntax, you can check out [this explanation from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_language_theory).

In particular, if you see some pattern followed by the **?** operator, it means that pattern is optional. So something like **digits(.digits)?** will match strings of the form **digits.digits** or just **digits** because the last **(.digits)** part is optional.

I would guess that **digits** is a placeholder for a series of numeric digits (0-9). So something like **digits(.digits)?** would match strings like "33.5", "0.8", "1.892", "7", etc.

Comment: **digits** should be a placeholder for consecutive numeric digits (the plural form of digit).

Comment: @Apass.Jack ah thanks, nice catch! Edited to fix